# Modeling Eyelid for animation

Tags: modeling

That's my first post so first of all - Hello everybody.

I am creating a simple cartoon character and I am stuck at one thing - eyelid for a specific shape of the eye just like in the attached image. Eyes are separated from the body because I want to animate them occasionally outside of it. I can't figure out how to model eyelids that can be fully closed from top to bottom.

Thanks for any tip.[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please elaborate a bit? what does "how to model eyelids" means? do you mean what kind of shape you could give to the eyelids? do you plan to always display the eyelid? etc...